# Node.JS and MYSQL How do I store a column value into a variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I have been working on a registration/login system for a theoretical bank and I'm trying to create accounts for the user who is signing up and adding it under their user ID however I'm not sure how to take the query from the database and put it into a variable so I can do this.

This is more or less how I'm trying to do it. However I'm not sure how to put the information that I'm grabbing into the userID variable

```
db.query('Select userID FROM users WHERE userEmail = ?', email, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        var userID = <userID from the database>

        if(userID !== undefined)
        {
            db.query('INSERT INTO accounts SET ?', {users_userID: userID, accountType: 'Checking', accountBalance: 100}, (error, results) =>{
                console.log('creating checking');
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });

            db.query('INSERT INTO accounts SET ?', {users_userID: userID, accountType: 'Savings', accountBalance: 100}, (error, results) =>{
                console.log('creating savings');
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: As a side note: be careful about the back to back *non-nested* `db.query`'s inside of that second `if` statement. It doesn't seem to matter in this scenario, but you will have cases where the second one will occur first or the first could fail and the second one could insert (which may be problematic if you dropped the savings and only have the checking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results` variable should contain the data retrieved from the db query.

Example (if there is a field called 'userID'):

```js
db.query(... (error, results) => {
    var userID = results[0].userID;
}
```

Comment: Okay I guess I was just missing the array and that is why it was coming up as undefined. let me give this a try.